# Pureconfig Typesafe Config with Hierarchical Root Keys

Tags: scala, pureconfig

I have the below in application.conf and trying to figure out the best way to define my class class to load the configurations:

```
allKeys {
   mysql {
     dev {
       host = <host1>
       user = <user1>
     }
     prod {
       host = <host1>
       user = <user1>
   }
   hdfs {
     endpoint = <host1>
     port = <port1>
   }
}

my case classes:
  case class Settings(mysql: DbSettings, hdfs: HdfsSettings)
  case class DbSettings(host: String, user: String)
  case class HdfsSettings(endpoint: String, port: String)
```

I'm having issues with knowing how to properly load this so that it doesn't fail when it looks for similar keys in hdfs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define your case class's to fit the config structure.

```
case class HdfsConfig(endpoint: String, port: Int)
case class DbConfig(host: String, user: String)
case class MySqlConfig(dev: DbConfig, prod: DbConfig)
case class AllConfigs(mysql: MySqlConfig, hdfs: HdfsConfig)

case class MyConfig(allKeys: AllConfigs)
```

Now you can read these as,

```
loadConfig[MyConfig](conf)
```